# How do I stop displaying "warranties" notice when logging in on tty1 console

Tags: console

That messages the ubuntu displays about warranties and suggestions for help.

The only thing I want to see is the version and status of updates.

Actually if someone can tell me how to create my own messages to display that would be great.

Comment: Please leave personal opinion out of your questions.

Answer (score 14):

The text you are looking for is inside

```
/etc/legal
```

---

```
The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.
```

Before you start editing this: as far as I know this is shown ONCE per user logging in.  When there is a file

```
~/.cache/motd.legal-displayed
```

it will NOT be shown. So just create that and it will be gone. Easiest method is to execute this command:

```
touch ~/.cache/motd.legal-displayed
```

---

If you want to add your own messages you can add a file to

```
/etc/update-motd/
```

Currently it will hold:

```
00-header     90-updates-available  98-fsck-at-reboot
10-help-text  91-release-upgrade    98-reboot-required
```

The file names are executed in alphabetical order and their name sort of states what it shows. 00-header is the "Welcome..." text. 10-help-text shows the URL to the Ubuntu documentation etc.